# Not found : Type Build (Unresolved 'Build')

Tags: scala, sbt-assembly

I'm getting the following set of errors, which I belive is caused by the sbt-assembly plugin that I is used. 
In fact the object declaration of ;

```
object Build extends **Build** { (here Build is unresolved).
```

The error is as follows,

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/><pre>
[info] Loading settings from assembly.sbt,plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\ShakthiW\IdeaProjects\TestProject\project
[error] <path>\Build.scala:4:22: not found: type Build
[error] object Build extends Build{
[error]                      ^
[error] <path>\Build.scala:8:80: value map is not a member of (sbt.TaskKey[sbt.librarymanagement.UpdateReport], sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File], sbt.SettingKey[String])
[error]     def copyDepTask = copyDependencies <<= (update, crossTarget, scalaVersion) map {
[error]                                                                                ^
[error] <path>\Build.scala:19:16: too many arguments (3) for method apply: (id: String, base: java.io.File)sbt.Project in object Project
[error] Note that 'settings' is not a parameter name of the invoked method.
[error]       settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
[error]                ^
[error] three errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

A quick resolve is highly appreciated. 
My Build.scala looks like this.

```
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object MyBuild extends Build {

  lazy val copyDependencies = TaskKey[Unit]("copy-dependencies")

  def copyDepTask = copyDependencies <<= (update, crossTarget, scalaVersion) map {
    (updateReport, out, scalaVer) =>
      updateReport.allFiles foreach { srcPath =>
        val destPath = out / "lib" / srcPath.getName
        IO.copyFile(srcPath, destPath, preserveLastModified=true)
      }
  }

  lazy val root = Project(
    "root",
    file("."),
    settings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
      copyDepTask
    )
  )
}
```

Also, I do rekon there is a issue with sbt-assembly upgrades as well which I'm not entirely aware of.

Comment: What version of sbt? How does you `Build.scala` look like?

Comment: @mfirry My sbt version is 1.0.1

Comment: @mfirry I've edited question with the Build file.

Comment: Per the release notes for SBT 1.0, it looks like support for deprecated build definitions like this have been dropped – time to migrate to build.sbt. See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-013x.html

Comment: @Hugh I did try out the steps as mentioned there. Now the error is an unresolved dependency pointing to the plugin with a warning on SBT (as if a conflict between 1.0.1 and 1.0.2).

Answer (score 2):

In sbt version 1.0.x, some key dependencies operators were removed. See the migration docs: https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Migrating-from-sbt-012x.html

Here is an short tutorial for writing Build.scala for sbt version 1.0.x: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/sbt-how-to-use-build.scala-instead-of-build.sbt.

You can also refer to build.scala of an existing project for more ref, eg. [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/series/7.3.x/project/build.scala).